# Unable to populate ListView from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

The error is `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

Below is my AsyncTask (it is in another class in a separate file)
**GetWarehouseSales.java**

```
public class GetWarehouseSales extends Activity {

    private String TAG = GetWarehouseSales.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Activity activityContext;
    //URL to get JSON details
    private static String url = "http://192.168.0.1/mycc/retrieve_ws.php";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sales_details;

    public GetWarehouseSales(Activity context){
        this.activityContext = context;
        sales_details = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void executeGWS(){
        new RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask().execute();
    }


    public class RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting you the best warehouse sales...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            //making a request to URL and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if(jsonStr != null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    //Getting JSON Array Node
                    JSONArray sales = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");
                    //looping through all results
                    for(int i = 0; i<sales.length();i++){
                        JSONObject s = sales.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = s.getString("title");
                        String description = s.getString("description");

                        HashMap<String,String> salesDetails = new HashMap<>();

                        //adding each child node to HashMap key =>value
                        salesDetails.put("title",title);
                        salesDetails.put("description",description);

                        //adding to array list
                        sales_details.add(salesDetails);
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG",sales_details.toString());
                }catch(final JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG,"Couldn't get json from server");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check logcat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }


            //update parsed JSON data into ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GetWarehouseSales.this, sales_details,R.layout.item_listview, new String[]{
                    "title","description"}, new int[]{R.id.text,R.id.description});
            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)  ;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        new GetWarehouseSales(this).executeGWS();


    }
```

The error points to this line:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GetWarehouseSales.this, sales_details,R.layout.item_listview, new String[]{
                    "title","description"}, new int[]{R.id.text,R.id.description});
```

I am trying to populate the data into the listview but unable to do so.

Comment: `doInBackground` should be building up a result that is then safely passed to the `onPostExecute`, by writing to a field of the activity (`sales_details`), you have made this unthread-safe.

Comment: Why is GetWarehouseSales extending an Activity?

And the line lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item); would most likely fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
new GetWarehouseSales(this).executeGWS();
```

to

```
executeGWS();
```

In general, you do it in the wrong way. As I've already answered here [NullPointerExeception for ProgressDialog in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414917/nullpointerexeception-for-progressdialog-in-asynctask/41414994#41414994) , you should define `AsynkTask` in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: The reason is that I might add more AsyncTask in the future. So I would like to keep MainActivity as minimum code as possible. Therefore, I have created AsyncTask in separate java files. Is there any alternative way to solve this ?

Comment: Try making `AsyncTask` __static__: `public static class RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask extends` and then `new GetWarehouseSales.RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask().execute();`

Answer (score 1):

As Vasily Kabunov points out, don't create a new instance of the class to call the method. Also don't extend `Activity` when it is not an `Activity`.

But also a major issue is `doInBackground` should be building up a result that is then safely passed to the `onPostExecute`, by writing to a field of the activity (`sales_details`), you have made this unthread-safe.

So do not access `sales_details` or other activity fields in `doInBackground`, do more like this:

```
public class RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>{ //return type set

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        //adding to array list
        result.add(salesDetails);
        ...
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        //update parsed JSON data into ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GetWarehouseSales.this, result,R.layout.item_listview, new String[]{
                "title","description"}, new int[]{R.id.text,R.id.description});
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kylas Was this any help to you?